# Load combobox with database value using Hibernate Spring

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, combobox

My question is simple, I created a combobox on:

```
<td><form:label path="city">City</form:label></td>
<td><form:select path="city" value="${nig.deve.found.domain.User.first_name}"></form:select></td>
```

What I intend to achieve is to load from the domain file User.java to populate the combobox directly from the database using hibernate. What is the best approach?

The first part is completed. My other quest is this: After it has been added to the combobox it appears as a list of string concatenated. For example, if there are 3 values in the column, it appears thus: tunji.femi.jide. How do I break it into a list?

Example:

```
     tunji
     femi
     jide
```

The DAO code is:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<User> allCities() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("SELECT first_name FROM User").list(); 
    }
```

The controller code is:

```
Map<String, Object> models = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        models.put("user", userService.allCities().toString());
        return new ModelAndView("Register", "models", models);
```

The jsp code is:

```
<td><form:label path="city">City</form:label></td>
<td><form:select path="city" items="${models}"></form:select></td>
```